# Custom header in nested TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a fairly complication navigation flow requirement for an app I'm working on.

I have a bottom tab bar, for each tab I'll be having a top tab bar for additional related views.

Which I have working, however on the videos tab in the nested "All" tab, I need to add a search bar to the header, and on the "Favourites" tab I'll be having yet another custom header with an "Edit" button at the top right.

How can I achieve this navigation whilst allowing React Navigation to co-ordinate everything. See images below:

What I don't want to do is disable the header at the MainNavigator level and enable it for particular routes. Or even worse embed the header and the tab bar on individual containers.

**routes.js**

```
import {
  StackNavigator,
  TabNavigator,
  DrawerNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import Feed from "./containers/Feed";
import Auth from "./containers/Auth";
import News from "./containers/News";
import Videos from "./containers/Videos";
import FavouriteVideos from "./containers/FavouriteVideos";

const DashboardNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: Feed
    },
    News: {
      screen: News
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "top"
  }
);

const VideoNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Videos: {
      screen: Videos,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "All"
      }
    },
    Favourites: {
      screen: FavouriteVideos
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "top"
  }
);

const MainNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: {
      screen: DashboardNavigator,
      navigationOptions: ({}) => ({
        title: "Dashboard"
      })
    },
    Video: {
      screen: VideoNavigator,
      navigationOptions: ({}) => ({
        title: "Videos"
      })
    }
  },
  {
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom"
  }
);

const AuthenticatedNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  App: {
    screen: MainNavigator
  }
});

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  LoggedOut: {
    screen: Auth
  },
  Authenticated: {
    screen: AuthenticatedNavigator
  }
});

export default RootNavigator;
```

**Snack**

https://snack.expo.io/H1qeJrLiM

**Images**

[image: Home]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react-navigation [`addListener`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) function with combination [`setParams`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#setparams-make-changes-to-route-params) to achieve desired behavior.

You can listen for focus and blur events and then change a parameter. Then in your route config you can look for this parameter and decide what to render for header. I [changed your snack](https://snack.expo.io/S1JkcALiM) to show a working example of what I am suggesting.

**Example**

```
const MainNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: {
      screen: DashboardNavigator,
      navigationOptions: ({}) => ({
        title: "Dashboard"
      })
    },
    Video: {
      screen: VideoNavigator,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        let title = 'Videos';
        navigation.state.routes.forEach((route) => {
          if(route.routeName === 'Videos' && route.params) {
            title = route.params.title;
          }
        });
        // I set title here but you can set a custom Header component
        return {
          tabBarLabel: 'Video',
          title
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom"
  }
);
```

---

```
export default class Videos extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.willFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      payload => {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({title: 'All Videos'});
      }
    );
    this.willBlurSubscription = props.navigation.addListener(
      'willBlur',
      payload => {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({title: 'Just Videos'});
      }
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
     this.willBlurSubscription.remove();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Videos </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Benny, setting title propagates to the root stack navigator. Providing more complicated functionality such as a search bar (which requires a custom header component) doesn't propagate. 

I did create a feature request: https://react-navigation.canny.io/feature-requests/p/tabbar-header-component-propagation
For that very thing. 

Apparently I do have to use `setParams` though https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2699